# javascript pattern matching object

Tags: javascript

Given a javascript object array eg.

```
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}]
```

is there a faster way of getting all the b values from each object which meet a specific criteria such as a = 1 to return something like

```
b_consolidated = [2,3]
```

instead of looping through every object in the array?

Comment: `objArray.filter(x => x.a === 1).map(x => x.b)`

Comment: Does this mean you're looking for a solution faster than O(n)? Or are you just trying to prevent iterating over the object properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to iterate over the array once, if you use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=example):

```js
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}]

let result = objArray.reduce((arr, val) => {
  if(val.a === 1)
    arr.push(val.b);
  return arr;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

This is as fast as it'll get, short of a manual `for` loop:

```js
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}]

let result = [];

for(var i = 0 ; i < objArray.length; i++){
  if(objArray[i].a === 1)
    result.push(objArray[i].b);
}

console.log(result);
```

[**Here's a JSPerf**](https://jsperf.com/reduce-concat-push) to illustrate the difference.
A manual `for` loop is by far the fastest.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **[Array#filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?v=example)** function to get the items of your criteria, then use **[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)** to get only `b` property.

```js
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}];

let values = objArray.filter(item => item.a === 1).map(item => item.b);

console.log(values);
```

Or you can do this in one loop

```js
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}];
let values = [];

objArray.forEach(item => {

  if(item.a === 1) {
      values.push(item.b);
  }
  
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: Note for the question: You are still looping through every object implicitly with `filter` and `map`. I do not think it is possible to solve the question in a way that doesn't involve looping at some point.

Comment: Looping twice, even.

Comment: And why? Only for returning item?

Comment: Filter is meant to be used when you want to _filter_ an array. What you're doing here is iterating over _all_ values of an array, then using only certain values. A `forEach` would be correct, there.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) in a single loop.

```js
let array = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, { a: 1, b: 3, c: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 }],
    result = array.reduce((r, o) => o.a === 1 ? r.concat(o.b) : r, []);

console.log(result);
```

Fastest version with for loop.

```js
let array = [{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, { a: 1, b: 3, c: 2 }, { a: 2, b: 5, c: 1 }],
    i, l,
    result = [];

for (i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (array[i].a === 1) {
        result.push(array[i].b);
    }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: If you're concerned about performance, this `concat` approach is [rather slow](https://jsperf.com/reduce-concat-push)

Comment: @Cerbrus, for a real speedy version, i would use a for loop, instead of some array prototypes for iterating.

Answer (score 1):

More faster would be using [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}];

objArray.reduce(function(res,obj){
   if(obj.a===1)
     res.push(obj.b);
   return res;
},[]);

// [2,3]
```

Comment: Instead of `==`, [preferably](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons) use `===`.

Answer (score -1):

In [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/docs/)

```
let objArray = [{a: 1, b: 2 , c:3},{a: 1, b:3, c:2},{a: 2, b:5, c:1}]

R.pipe(
  R.filter(R.propEq('a', 1)),
  R.pluck('b')
)(objArray)

// [2, 3]
```

- [Filter](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#filter) returns the array values matched by the condition.
- [Pluck](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pluck) returns a new list by plucking the same named property off all objects in the list supplied.

Edit 1:

Example of using the mentioned `reduce` pattern in Ramda:

```
R.reduce((acc, x) => R.ifElse(
  R.propEq('a', 1), 
  (item) => R.pipe(R.prop('b'), R.append(R.__, acc))(item), 
  R.always(acc)
)(x), [])(objArray)

// [2, 3]
```

Comment: So, in a question where the OP asks for fast code, you're: 1: loading a new library. 2: iterating over the array (at least) twice...